# Connect to multiple queue managers in different servers

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect a C++ application (using MQCONNX) based on a PaaS IBM MQ client to two different queue managers, each one based on a different server (one in a PaaS server and the other one in a Unix server). Unfortunately I am not able to do it as I am getting a message when I try to connect to the second server saying that it is not possible as it is connected to the first queue manager. I am using two different MQHCONN connections, one for each queue manager, but the problem is still there.

I have taken a look into this link, but I still have some doubts, as for example, from which server should I copy the CCDT to the client?

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/connecting-mq-clients-multiple-queue-managers-client-channel-definition-table-ccdt

Any help would be much appreciated, or even a quick sample of how to use CCDT, as right now I am completely stuck.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide sample code that can reproduce the error.   What exact MQRC error code do you get?  These days the CCDT can be produced with `runmqsc -n` independently of the qmgr.  In the latest version you can even use a JSON formatted CCDT.  What version of MQ client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Queue Manager 1 is called `MQG1` and Queue Manager 2 is called `MQG2` and these can be found using connection names of `machine1.com(1701)` and `machine2.com(1702)` respectively, and using channel names `MQG1.SVRCONN` and `MQG2.SVRCONN` respectively, you can create your CCDT, on your client application machine, thus:-

```
runmqsc -n
```

issue these commands into `runmqsc`:-

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(MQG1.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) CONNAME('machine1.com(1701)') QMNAME(MQG1)
DEFINE CHANNEL(MQG2.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) CONNAME('machine2.com(1702)') QMNAME(MQG2)
```

Then you can code your 2 x `MQCONN` (or `MQCONNX` if you need to specify any additional things on the connection) thus:-

```
#include <cmqc.h>                    /* Includes for MQI constants */
#include <cmqstrc.h>                 /* Convert MQRC into string   */

MQHCONN hConn1 = MQHC_UNUSABLE_HCONN;
MQHCONN hConn2 = MQHC_UNUSABLE_HCONN;
MQCHAR  QMName1[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = "MQG1";
MQCHAR  QMName2[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = "MQG2";
MQLONG  CompCode, Reason;

MQCONN(QMName1,
       &hConn1,
       &CompCode,
       &Reason);
if (CompCode)
{
  printf("MQCONN to %s failed with reason code %s (%d)\n", QMName1, MQRC_STR(Reason), Reason); 
}
MQCONN(QMName2,
       &hConn2,
       &CompCode,
       &Reason);
if (CompCode)
{
  printf("MQCONN to %s failed with reason code %s (%d)\n", QMName2, MQRC_STR(Reason), Reason); 
}
```

Take care with how you are linking your program. If you try to make two local connections, you will get a return code of `MQRC_ANOTHER_Q_MGR_CONNECTED`. Ensure you either link with the client library, set connection option `MQCNO_CLIENT` (which means you must use `MQCONNX`) or set the environment variable `MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT`.

You might find the following blog post useful additional reading:-

[IBM MQ Little Gem #30: MQ_CONNECT_TYPE](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/middleware/blogs/morag-hughson/2017/12/13/ibm-mq-little-gem-30-mq-connect-type)